# Converting epoch to datetime

Tags: sesam

I have the following entity:

```
{
  "q": 524480,
  "t": "~f1520825387781.23",
  "v": "~f8058.0147682"
}
```

How do i convert the "t" value to a datetime. The value is seconds since epoch.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `datetime` function, but first you must convert the epoch to an integer representing nanoseconds since epoch.

```
{
  "_id": "my-pipe",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "foo",
      "q": 524480,
      "t": "~f1520825387781.23",
      "v": "~f8058.0147682"
    }]
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["add", "timestamp",
          ["datetime",
            ["integer",
              ["*", 1e6, "_S.t"]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This gives you:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "foo",
    "timestamp": "~t2018-03-12T03:29:47.78123Z"
  }
]
```